# Fragment Incompatible Types error : Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Disclaimer : Android Level = Beginner
I am trying to use PApplet in android. I followed [this](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/wiki/Using-Eclipse-or-Android-Studio-for-Development) guide to set up the project in Android Studio

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.jess.processingtest;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment;
        fragment = new Sketch();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Sketch.Java**

```
package com.example.jess.processingtest;


import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Sketch extends PApplet {

//    @Override
    public void settings() {
        //Call size/fullscreen from here
        size(1000, 1000, P2D);
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        //Initialize one time stuffs here
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        //Finally draw from here
    }
}
```

The error shows up for fragment = new Sketch(); , stating **Incompatible types**. I also tried using **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;** which still gives me same error.

Comment: does `PApplet` extend `Fragment`?

Comment: It extends Activity. Noticed it in class implementation. `public class PApplet extends Activity implements PConstants, Runnable {...`

Comment: Then it is not a Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I found the package [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadprocessingandroidcorejar.htm). Is there a work around for this or am I absolutely asking the wrong questions?